# SQL Get Delimited Results for All Columns

Tags: sql, sybase

I'm working on a simple SQL statement to generate BCP files to be loaded into the database.

These BCP files are in the following format:

```
1|name|otherfield|otherfield1
```

To build files like this I'm currently doing:

```
SELECT id+"|"+name+"|"+otherfield+"|"+otherfield1+"\n" FROM table
```

Is there a select statement that will select `every column` without having to name them?

Something like

```
SELECT * with "|" from Table
```

Comment: Is that really the correct way to do it in the first place? What if one of your columns contains a "|"? Aren't there escaping rules you should be applying?

Comment: @deceze this is a very good point, unfortunately the script that reads these in is "out of my control" and expects | and doesn't support any escape characters. It's the good old "it works so don't touch it".

Comment: Before there was a mysql tag but it has been removed. Any idea why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select-into.html).

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'filename'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM yourtable;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select-into.html

Comment: This is for a Sybase database, not MYSQL

Comment: Strange... It was tagged mysql before, but the tag is gone now.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the output in a file then you can try this

```
SELECT *
INTO OUTFILE 'D://abc.txt'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
FROM table
```

here I have used `\r\n` for outputting each row on a new line (ON windows)

Comment: This for a Sybase database, not MySql

Answer (score 1):

For Sybase ASE, why not just change the delemiter using the built in **bcp** utility.  It will capture all the columns by default.

```
bcp MYDATABASE..MYTABLE out MYTABLEFILE.bcp -Uusername -Ppassword -SMYSERVER -c -t|
```

You have to use the **-t** option to set the column delimeter, which can only be used with the **-c** option specifying a 'character' (human readable) based bcp output.  If you are on a Unix/Linux based system, you may have to escape the pipe, e.g. **-\t**